# 'SO_REUSEPORT' is not defined on Windows 7

Tags: python, sockets

I found multiple answers that suggest using the SO_REUSEPORT socket option when multiple UDP clients need to listen for broadcasts on the same port.  However I'm getting an error that this option is not available.  Using python 2.7

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
try:
    s.bind(('', MYPORT))
except:
    print "Error connecting to the UDP stream."


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qsorder.py", line 119, in <module>
    s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
NameError: name 'SO_REUSEPORT' is not defined
```

I've tried SO_REUSEADDR and it does not give an error but only one client receives broadcasts.  Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: What do you call "broadcast"? What address are datagrams sent to?

Comment: the udp packets are sent to the broadcast address for the subnet (255 in the last octet). I'm trying to run multiple instances of the script on the same PC and each listen to these broadcasts without exclusively locking up the port to which the datagrams are sent.

Comment: With `255.255.255.0` network mask?

Comment: yes /24 mask. does it really make a difference if they are broadcast or unicast, at least in this specific case? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `SO_BROADCAST` option on each socket:

```
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
```

`SO_REUSEPORT` is not standard and usually means same thing as `SO_REUSEADDR` where supported.

Comment: that flag didn't work by itself, however with both SO_BROADCAST and SO_REUSEADDR set it looks better and multiple instances are receiving the packets!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - you need both. And oops, didn't see the obvious omission of `SO_BROADCAST` in your original code.

Comment: more on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t?rq=1